# React component is not rendered after refresh (probably useEffect issue)

Tags: reactjs

I set routing for search which looks something like: `/home/search/?searchInput=:searchInput`
When I'm using the interface Created the search works as expected however when on the search result after refreshing everything is lost.

This is my code when in Search results component

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom";
    import ListElement from "../EntitnyPresention/ListElement";
    import axios from "axios";
    import "../css/test.css";
    const SearchResult = (props) => {
      const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = React.useState([]);
      const getSearchResults = async () => {
      await axios(
      `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/search/?searchInput=${props.match.params.searchInput}`,
      { method: "GET" }
    ).then((response) => {
      setSearchResults(() => [...response.data]);
    });
    };

     useEffect(async () => {
       await getSearchResults();
     }, [props.match.params.searchInput]);
```

What I'm missing, probably somthing in `useEffect`